# I hope your brain won't fall apart

Tags: riddle, word

I'm the one to be told
at the very end 
just get rid of the old
before you descend

I'm the tie on your neck 
if you slice it apart 
and the third in the group 
rhyming is hard

I'm the first of the group
and I will be kind 
Think of my age
and it's me who you'll find

Although mentioned last 
Im the easiest of all 
If you can not find me 
start again after fall

This is my riddle
and you know the deal 
Find out the answer -
What is it I feel?

Super secret solution ahead:

> Spoiler: It is something you can feel and it has 4 letters. I'm sure you already knew that. Also it has nothing to do with religion of any kind.
>  I focused on playing with grammar and letters here. Sticking close to the words without interpreting may help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can feel:

> HEAT

Explanation:

> 'H'  $\rightarrow$ "age" sounds like H (first in the group)
> 'E'  $\rightarrow$ tie-it (and third letter of tie); also the third in "*th**e** group*" 
> 'A'  $\rightarrow$ "start again" the TITLE! - "brain won't FALL **A**PART" (brilliant!!)
> 'T'  $\rightarrow$ told-old (last of the group)

Comment: Well, there is only one guy who found out about the "a" so far. I'd really like to hear it before I mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Well it says to start _after_ fall

Answer (score 12):

> Cold?

It's what people feel when they're about to die, 
how your neck will feel without a tie,
it's how the third in the group will feel without a special friend,
It's what you'll feel at fall's end.

Comment: I admit that your solution is very beautiful. Although it is not my solution and it doesn't cover all the clues.

Comment: Although four clue stanzas... four letters. Not a coincidence, methinks, as I only have the last letter for sure.

Comment: That's what I thought too...

Comment: Don't forget about the order.

Comment: @generalcrispy The riddle also says in the beginning, "just get rid of the old before you descend." Get rid of the "old" in "c**old**" and you are, in the end, left with "c" (des - **c** - **end**). So maybe it isn't a coincidence... or I am merely overthinking at this point ;)

Answer (score 3):

If it's not Marko's answer then maybe it's

> Time
>  slice it apart and you can make tie. it's at the end of most datetime formats. you can feel time (old). At the end of fall we have daylights saving where we change time (this is where year fits better) in an zero based array of dimensions it would be the third (quite a stretch)

Comment: Another solution far from what I could ever have imagined.

Answer (score 3):

> hate 
>  1) I think of 'age' and I realize it sounds a lot like 'h'. 
>  3) Slice the 'tie' apart? Ok, then that should be the "t". 
>  4) I can see the 'e' in the 'end', although I'm not sure if I interpreted this correctly. 
>  2) No clue needed like you said: 'a'. Plus, if I start again I'm right at the beginning, and the first letter of the alphabet is 'a'.

Comment: That was my initial guess, too, but I thought the last letter was a 't'.

Comment: That's a nice version for sure. As you assumed correctly you have some 'differences' left there compared to my solution.

Answer (score 3):

> SWAG

- SOLD - (to get rid of) minus OLD
- Split Bowtie , third letter
- Look at beginning of AGE
- Start A-Gain after fall - after a Fall to start to Gain

  You did not know you could feel this ? Nether did I :
  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=swag+level

Comment: Close enough I should say

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if this you feel right now but..

> HURT, T from told, R from apart, U from splitting the tie and removing the 3rd part, H from age..

Comment: That's 2 out of 4 for you!

Comment: @bluefire6 U from splitting the tie and removing 3rd part?

Answer (score 3):

> heat. h from age. e if you slice "i" and "t" away from tie. a first in the group of letters in the alphabet. t from told - old.

Comment: The closest thing possible I guess.

Comment: edited but @d'lar'corp got it.

Comment: He is kind of crazy about solving puzzles. He is everywhere!

Answer (score 2):

> so is this how heat comes to pass? ... 
>  h from "age",
>  e from "eeesiest",
>  a from third letter in apart? no idea,
>  t from told - old

Comment: 2 out of 4 again. Maybe you should try to expand your efforts.

Comment: I'm fairly certain on the first two, though, mostly because I like the way I came up with them.

Comment: You seem to have the right thoughts, generally. But you will have to try again.

Comment: Really stumped on the 'a', honestly. Unless the neck one isn't the third position after all.

Comment: For you seem to be really committed I can reveal that the "neck one" really is not the third of the group but the third in "the group". Hope you don't mind my confusing means!

Comment: In that case, I got nothing. Eagerly awaiting a correct explanation by _someone_.

Comment: I really hope you will laugh about the solution for the "a"!

Comment: Oh, I started after the wrong "f all" first time, then. Nice riddle, except for the tie part, that was a bit of a stretch.

Comment: You absolutely walked right into my trap ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> love??

Told at the very end of every fairty tale??

decend as in fall, but young people arnt considered this by elders. its just a phase.

It is the restrainst of finding it released after the ceremony

It is kind, almost all the time but I digress

it is easy if right.

you usually fall into this.

They are my reasons as flimsy as the base might be.

Comment: Very creative! However, not my solution.

Comment: Fair enough, ill give it another go later.

Answer (score 0):

> LOST:
>  T - last letter, cutting off old from told,
>  S - third letter, looks like tie unraveled,
>  L - roman numeral for fifty, because I doubt X, C, D, M would fit ;) and
>  O - o**f all**

Comment: 1 out of 4, you can do it!